# Why index on json field not working? Django, large database

Tags: python, json, django, database, optimization

I have a model in django that has a json field that holds the nutritional values of a meal.

```
from django.db import models


class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    portions_count = models.IntegerField()
    attributes = models.JSONField()
```

I have a million meal records and would like to search based on attributes (gte, lte). Example atrributes field:

```
{"cep": 21.71, "eng": 23.37, "fep": 40.91, "pep": 27.29}
```

Example view:

```
class MealView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        meals = Meal.objects.filter(attributes__eng__gte=12, attributes__cep__gte=12)[:50]
        return render(request, 'meals.html', {
            'meals': meals
        })
```

...and more advanced queries (attributes, portions count and name together).

Queries can take a few seconds and if the database is overloaded, it takes longer.

We tried:

```
GinIndex(fields=['attributes']),
```

or

```
Index(fields=['attributes'])
```

But indexes was not used. (checked in postgres via sql query, pg_stat_all_indexes table and explain select)

I know that it would definitely be better if the attributes were not in JSON. Ultimately we will try to change it, but at the moment we are looking for a JSON solution.

Comment: Have you tried setting `jsonb_path_ops`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#opclasses

Comment: Still not using indexing: `Seq Scan on dm_meal  (cost=0.00..45610.00 rows=111111 width=171)   Filter: (((attributes -> 'cep'::text) <= '12'::jsonb) AND ((attributes -> 'eng'::text) >= '12'::jsonb))`

Comment: OK, sorry then, not sure I have anything else to suggest.